# Can anyone help my find find error in django?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I have a project which has 2 child apps: "visit" and "main". The error is in base.html file in href for the navigation bar. 
I am facing No reverse match found error.

main/base.html:

```
    {%load staticfiles%}

    <link href="{%static "main/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"%}" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="{%static "main/css/small-business.css"%}" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home.html">Ekyam</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href='{%url 'main:home'%}'>Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href='{%url 'main: incubators'%}'>Incubators</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
{%block content%}

{%endblock%}
```

This is the error that I am facing

```
NoReverseMatch at /home.html

Reverse for ' incubators' not found. ' incubators' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/home.html
Django Version:     1.11.3
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for ' incubators' not found. ' incubators' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Exception Location:     C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
Python Executable:  C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version:     3.6.1
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\my dell\\Desktop\\Projects\\junityme'
```

Help would be appreciated.
site urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('visit.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('main.urls', namespace='main')),

]

from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'/incubators/', views.incubators, name='incubators'),
    url(r'/about/', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

I have posted the the url files. As you can see I have declared name space for the "main" app for referencing it in base.html.
What I have done in "visit" app I have setup registration/login portal which redirects user to the "main" app.  Loging in will unlock the main features of the app.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'main/home.html')


def incubators(request):
    return render(request, 'main/incubators.html')

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("dsfsddsf")
```

Comment: You have a space in reverse: `{%url 'main: incubators'%}`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. No reverse match at /home.html

Comment: Can you post your urls.py file?

Comment: I have edited the question and given more details

Comment: can you post your `views.py` file?

Comment: You should remove the space as Borut suggested and use `{% url 'main:incubators' %}` instead. If that still doesn't work, then the error message will be different. In that case, please update your code with the current template and error message.

Comment: I was able to solve this error. But I am facing another one now. My HTML files for incubator(in navigation var) and about are not getting displayed. Like once it shows home page html, if you click on other link same page remains only the url changes. I know this sounds confusing

Comment: You need to fix the urls.py as I said in my answer. Note that this is a completely separate issue, so if you’re still stuck you should accept Rik’s answer and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your urls. Making these changes won't fix your specific error but you should do them anyway.

In your main urls.py, you should update your import, and remove the namespace:

```
from django.urls import include, url 
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('visit.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),

]
```

In your `main/urls.py`, add `app_name = 'main'` now that you have removed the namespace from the `include()`. Your regexes should begin with `^` and end with a `$` (don't include a `$` with `include()`). The regexes should not have a slash at the beginning.

```
app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^incubators/$', views.incubators, name='incubators'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error reports:

```
Reverse for ' incubators' not found.
```

There is a space before ' incubators', otherwise it would have said 'incubators'. Borut stated this already.

To solve this you will have to use:

```
'{%url 'main:incubators'%}'
```

instead of

```
'{%url 'main: incubators'%}'
```

I only removed the space in front of incubators. You seem to have done the same, but still get the error. In that case, did you use this line multiple times in 'home.html'? Because if you did, you have to change all the instances ofcourse.

If you correctly changed the above code but still get the same error, like you said, the error should look a little different now. It should now say:

```
Reverse for 'incubators' not found. 'incubators' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Note that it now should not have the initial space in front of 'incubators'.

Just trying to be thorough here.

Comment: I was able to solve this error. But I am facing another one now. My HTML files for incubator(in navigation var) and about are not getting displayed. Like once it shows home page html, if you click on other link same page remains only the url changes. I know this sounds confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. Could you be more specific? Often when I try to write down a problem that I walk into, as if I was explaining it to someone else, it helps me get new ideas on how to solve it.